# How does CRM 2011 load and manage plugins in sandbox mode?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have 2 plugin assemblies which are sharing the proxy code generated by crmsvcutil. The proxy code file tends to be large(14+ MB) and it seems to bloat up the Plugin Dlls.

I am thinking that it might make sense to offset the proxy code into a separate assembly and deploy it to the GAC on the CRM server.This would reduce the bloat in the plugin assemblies and also reduce the memory footprint since only a single copy of the proxy code would be loaded into the process space.

The question is, how does CRM load individual plugin assemblies? 
Are they all loaded into the same process space or are they loaded into separate app domains?

If they are loaded into separate app domains then it defeats the purpose of having a separate assembly containing the generated proxy code since it will be loaded separately into both app domains anyways.

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Any special reason why you have define multiple plugin assemblies, instead of encapsulating them in one assembly?

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question directly, but if bloat is the problem, there is a number of extensions to the crmsvcutil out there that will allow you to filter the generated class file to only include the entities that you wish to play with.  I've done so before (at a previous company and have since lost the source.  Grrr!) with success, achieving a class file of a few kb rather than mb.

A quick google search took me to... http://fourbusyxrmarchitects.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/filtering-the-list-of-early-bound-classes-generated-by-the-code-generation-tool-crmsvcutil-for-crm-2011-2/

Comment: Interesting. The issue is to figure out the list of all the entities/related entities,so on and so forth in order to generate a minimalistic proxy. This in itself becomes a maintenance/management headache. My thought was to share the proxy code by GACing it but the issue I'm running into is that the plugin registration tool does not like references to the proxy types defined in this custom assembly and will not register the plugin. Is there a way to achieve this?